# Prove or give a counter-example for the inequality

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

Prove or give a counter-example for the following:

$\frac{2}{\gamma}[\sqrt{(1+\gamma (n-1))(1+\gamma (s -1))}-(1+\gamma (s -1))] \leq n-s$

where $n,s$ natural numbers with $n \geq 2$, $0<s<n-1$ and $\gamma$ a real in (0,1).

Comment: Under what theory are asked to prove this?

Comment: @Peter Tamaroff: Any correct proof or counter-example provided will do.

Comment: I'm just saying it because the $\gamma(s-1)$ reminds me of convex functions.

Comment: @Peter Tamaroff: you can use theory of convex functions if you wish.

Comment: Say you try to bound the left hand side from above: $\frac{2}{\gamma}[\sqrt{(1+\gamma (n-1))(1+\gamma (s -1))}-(1+\gamma (s -1))] \leq \frac{2}{\gamma}[\sqrt{(1+\gamma (n-1))^2}-(1+\gamma (s -1))] \leq \frac{2}{\gamma}\gamma(n-s)$ which is not a good bound

Comment: Say now that you would like to see what happens when $\gamma$ approaches $0$, you will then have a situation in which $\frac{2}{0}0$ in which you can not say anything.

Comment: peb, the thought process in your previous two comments would be a welcome addition to the body of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(\gamma)$ is your left side, 
$$ \frac{df}{d\gamma} = {\frac {-2-\gamma\,s+2\,\gamma-\gamma\,n+2\,\sqrt { \left( 1+\gamma\,n
-\gamma \right)  \left( 1+\gamma\,s-\gamma \right) }}{{\gamma}^{2}
\sqrt { \left( 1+\gamma\,n-\gamma \right)  \left( 1+\gamma\,s-\gamma
 \right) }}}$$
The limit of this as $\gamma \to 0+$ is 
$-(n-s)^2/4$, which is negative.  If we set the numerator equal $0$, subtract the square root term from both sides, square and simplify we find $\gamma^2 (n-s)^2 = 0$.  So $f'(\gamma) < 0$ on $(0,\infty)$, and in particular $f(\gamma) < \lim_{\gamma \to 0+} f(\gamma) = n-s$.

Comment: Yes, this is correct as $\gamma$ approaches $0$ from the right. But it is the half way there. We have to check also what happens as $\gamma$ tends to 1.

Comment: No, we don't.   $f$ is decreasing on $(0,\infty)$.  Nothing special happens as $\gamma \to 1$.

Comment: Yes you are correct, the monotonicity will solve the problem. So the solution is complete.

Comment: Is there a possibility that in the numerator of the expression of $f^'$ you provided, instead of -2 we should have -4? I just wanted to verify the calculations again (using both maple and paper) and it seems this way... This -4 might make some difference in applying L'Hospital (have not checked this yet)...

Comment: This is exactly what Maple gave me, and in this instance I trust it.  Here's my Maple code (note that I use $g$ instead of $\gamma$, which to Maple is a constant).

> f:= 2/g*(sqrt((1+g*(n-1))*(1+g*(s-1))) - (1+g*(s-1)));

> simplify(diff(f, g));

Comment: you are right. By mistake I was working with >f := 2*((1+(1+x*(n-1))*(1+x*(s-1)))^(1/2)-1-x*(s-1))/x   in maple (and in paper) which has an extra 1 in the sqrt that introduces the extra -2 in the differentiation. Again you are very right! Thanks!